# XeLaTeX problem with a vector arrow

Tags: xetex

I am trying to write `$\overrightarrow{V}_{AB}$` with the vector over only `V`, but when I do this then the subscript `AB` goes far from `V`. On the other hand when I use the vector over the `V` and `AB` it seems wrong and not so beautiful. What am I doing wrong? Thank you very much!

Comment: Any reason against `$\vec{V}_{AB}$`?

Comment: I didn't know that command! Thank you!

Comment: Then you should read some introductory material like the [Dickimaw LaTeX Books](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex).

Comment: I will consider them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `unicode-math` along with XeLaTeX, there's no difference in what's printed with or without the arrow over the V; only the arrow length changes if you use `\vec` or `\overrightarrow`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\linespread{1.05} % if you have arrows over capital letters

\begin{document}
$V_{AB}$ \sbox0{$V_{AB}$}\the\wd0

$\vec{V}_{AB}$ \sbox0{$\vec{V}_{AB}$}\the\wd0

$\overrightarrow{V}_{AB}$ \sbox0{$\overrightarrow{V}_{AB}$}\the\wd0
\end{document}
```

The `\sbox` commands are just to print the width of the material, showing that the widths are the same.

[image]

Of course, the letter shapes in this case leave a hole, which should be corrected visually. It's a case similar to `$\sqrt{\log x}$`, where adding a thin space is better

```
$\sqrt{\,\log x}$
```

or `$x^2/2$` where a negative thin space is recommended

```
$x^2\!/2$
```

Here's the realizations, left without the correction, right with the correction:

[image]

So, in your case, I'd suggest

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\linespread{1.05} % if you have arrows over capital letters

\begin{document}
$V_{\!AB}$                           

$\vec{V}_{\!AB}$

$\overrightarrow{V}_{\!AB}$ 

\end{document}
```

[image]

I would definitely not recommend using `\overrightarrow` without `unicode-math`, as the result is appalling awful

[image]

and I'm not referring to the space between the variable and the subscript, but to the size of the arrow, which is too large.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to TeX.se! :-)

Try this: `$\overrightarrow{V}_{\!AB}$`.

The `\!` inserts negative horizontal spacing.

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: @Adam: How strange; it should. Try multiple `\!` in a row, e.g. `$\overrightarrow{V}_{\!\!\!\!AB}$` just to see if it makes a difference. If not, please put your full LaTeX code in your original question.

Comment: That worked!Why there was that problem though? Shouldn't without these corrections work the first time?

Comment: `\overrightarrow` creates a `\vbox`: a rectangle which, by default, does not overlap with other boxes. Such boxes can have visible content anywhere inside (or even outside) their bounds, so making them overlap will often be the wrong thing to do. Unfortunately, (La)TeX cannot take every possible situation into account. That's why there are ways to make manual corrections.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `\overrightarrow` produces a box. When a subscript is added to a box, it treats it as a rectangle, and can't see what's inside. When a subscript is added to a character, it sees the italic correction of that character (roughly proportional to the amount of slant) and compensates for it. The easy work-around is to insert negative space, with the amount based on trial and error. The difficult way is to try to measure the necessary amount of negative space automatically:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\def\overrightarrowwithsubscript#1{\mathpalette{\@oraws{#1}}}
\def\@oraws#1#2#3{%
  \begingroup
  \setbox0=\hbox{$#2{{#1}_{#3}}$}%
  \setbox2=\hbox{$#2{\overrightarrow{#1}_{#3}}$}%
  \@tempdima=\wd2 \advance\@tempdima-\wd0
  \overrightarrow{#1}_{\hskip-\@tempdima #3}
  \endgroup}
\begin{document}
$\overrightarrow{V}_{AB} \qquad \overrightarrowwithsubscript{V}{AB}$

\bigskip
$\frac{\overrightarrow{V}_{AB}}{\overrightarrow{V}_{AB}}\qquad
\frac{\overrightarrowwithsubscript{V}{AB}}{\overrightarrowwithsubscript{V}{AB}}$
\end{document}
```

[image: pdflatex output]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `esvect` package: it manages the subscript with a `\vv*`command, the arrow doesn't collide with what is underneath and you can choose between eight forms of arrow. Here is an example, to be compared with `\overrightarrow`:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[f]{esvect}

\begin{document}

\[ \vv*{V}{AB}\qquad\vv*{V}{\!AB}\qquad \overrightarrow{V}_{AB}  \]

\end{document}
```

[image]